# How to identify which web service is beeing evaluated in delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap

I am using a SOAP web service in an iOS app. I use two web methods. I am able to get the result of the first method without problems. I need to use more than one web method in the same ViewController.

- How can I know which web method is being evaluated in the delegate if the two web methods return a result with the same name?
- Should I write a delegate for each method?
- How do you work with more than one web method in the same ViewController?

Comment: couldn't get it ... u calling more than one service in same view controller ??/.

Comment: @Lea-rner no, I am calling different methods of the same web service. I have two soap messages, one soap message for each button in the view. The problem is that the two soap messages use the same delegate and I am not able to identify which of the two is being executed there.